# How to set an OAuth Access Token with C#

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api, google-sheets, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm new in C# and google api.

I have url for Access Token generation:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds&
response_type=token&
redirect_uri=https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground&
client_id={my_client_ID}`

The answer is:
`https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/#access_token=ya29.iQLRHrmgKRmOnKnQjTqaBsmuCj4lV1m2wwhpA726wVNOGURIo2h6gTj1IdmGQ5Aa6OIrAQ&
token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599`

I'm use this example from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets, to get access manually:

```
  string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
  Console.WriteLine(authorizationUrl);
  Console.WriteLine("Please visit the URL above to authorize your OAuth "
    + "request token.  Once that is complete, type in your access code to "
    + "continue...");
  parameters.AccessCode = Console.ReadLine();

  OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
  string accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;
  Console.WriteLine("OAuth Access Token: " + accessToken);

  GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory =
      new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1", parameters);
  SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
  service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
```

How can I with C# get access_token by link and than use it for my spreadsheets? Is there any .SetAccessToken(parameters)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved the problem by myself.
The code is:

```
string CLIENT_ID = your_client_id;
string CLIENT_SECRET = your_client_secret;
string SCOPE = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds";
string REDIRECT_URI = "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground";
string REFRESH_TOKEN = your_refresh_token;
OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;
parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;
parameters.Scope = SCOPE;
parameters.RefreshToken = REFRESH_TOKEN;
OAuthUtil.RefreshAccessToken(parameters);
```

Now you have access to google spreadsheets!